# What is the difference between res.setHeader('status',400); and res.status(400);?

Tags: node.js, express, response, status

I'm not sure what the exact difference is. Also, which one is better to be used to set response status?

Comment: No diff, but second approach is more common and safe

Answer (score 1):

[Express documentation says about res.status(code)](http://expressjs.com/fr/api.html)

> Sets the HTTP status for the response. It is a chainable alias of
>   Node’s response.statusCode.

---

[Node.js documentation says about response.statusCode](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_statuscode)

> When using implicit headers (not calling response.writeHead()
>   explicitly), this property controls the status code that will be sent
>   to the client when the headers get flushed.

---

And tho about [setHeaders](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)

> For this option, specify a function to set custom response headers.
>   Alterations to the headers must occur synchronously.

---

**Summary**

`res.setHeader` manipulate synchronously the headers (right now).

`res.status` will set the headers when they 'll get flushed.